# Postgres UPDATE much slower when WHERE clause omitted

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for clues in understanding why an `UPDATE` query became much slower when a filter on a `WHERE` clause was omitted.

The original version of the query, run 2 million times under load, averaged 6ms per query:

```sql
UPDATE items

SET name = $1,
      updated_at = now(),
      txid = txid_current(),
      version = version + 1

WHERE filter1 = $2 AND filter2 = $3 AND version = $4
  RETURNING *;
```

When I take out `AND version = $4`, the latency under the same load test is **far** worse (236ms):

```sql
UPDATE items

SET name = $1,
      updated_at = now(),
      txid = txid_current(),
      version = version + 1

WHERE filter1 = $2 AND filter2 = $3
  RETURNING *;
```

There is a unique index on the tuple of `filter1 + filter2`, so it should always be matching at most one record. And PG would have to read the entire record in order to generate a new MVCC record (there are other fields not updated in this query), so it would *seem* that `version = version + 1` should have roughly the same cost either way.

For some reasons to do with other parts of our app API design, I need to remove the `version` clause from this query.

What should I be looking at so as not to suffer this performance loss?

---

Per request from @Laurenz Albe, here are the `EXPLAIN` results:

```
with version clause:

UPDATE items
  SET name = $1,
      updated_at = now(),
      txid = txid_current(),
      version = version + 1
  WHERE filter1 = $2 AND filter2 = $3 AND version = $4
  RETURNING *;

Update on items  (cost=0.54..8.58 rows=1 width=637) (actual time=0.553..0.559 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=57
  ->  Index Scan using filter1_and_filter2 on items  (cost=0.54..8.58 rows=1 width=637) (actual time=0.064..0.070 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((filter2)::text = 'VBHNTZFLRX1575420065'::text) AND ((filter1)::text = 'UpdateNotifLoadTest'::text))
        Filter: (version = 191)
        Buffers: shared hit=6
Planning time: 0.138 ms
Execution time: 0.609 ms

---------

without version clause:

UPDATE items
  SET name = $1,
      updated_at = now(),
      txid = txid_current(),
      version = version + 1
  WHERE filter1 = $2 AND filter2 = $3
  RETURNING *;

Update on items  (cost=0.54..8.57 rows=1 width=637) (actual time=161.899..161.929 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=377
  ->  Index Scan using filter1_and_filter2 on items  (cost=0.54..8.57 rows=1 width=637) (actual time=0.102..0.131 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((filter2)::text = 'RXDJPVBHNT1575419999'::text) AND ((filter1)::text = 'UpdateNotifLoadTest'::text))
        Buffers: shared hit=25
Planning time: 0.140 ms
Execution time: 161.977 ms
```

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries.

Comment: Maybe you have an index with version in it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I've edited the original question with those results.

Comment: In those, the version without the additional clause is actually faster? On the other hand, it seems like you didn't pass real data, as it didn't find a row to update

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll see if I can capture a real query from the load test and try again.

Comment: Regarding your update, the version with the `where` clause did not update anything (`actual … rows=0`), so it's not really comparable to the one without the `where` clause that does update one row.

Comment: Ah, good catch. The `version = $4` clause is part of a conflict-avoidance mechanism in the system, which past experience suggests is about 4% of the time. I'll re-run the test and look for an example where `actual … rows = 1`.

Comment: Just realized: I run the `EXPLAIN` case after determining that the original query succeeded. Using the same parameters as for the query itself. Which means the `version` clause will never succeed when running `EXPLAIN`. D'oh! I'll retool and re-run the test with corrected behavior, but I may not have new results until tomorrow.

Comment: @Bergi: Updated with corrected methodology here. `rows=1` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Weird. Re-run several times today and can not reproduce this.</strike>

I had a flaw in my earlier methodology. Can still reproduce. Per request from @Bergi, I have updated with a capture from live load test with real data.

Comment: The latency numbers (6ms vs 236ms) reported in the original question from last week recurred with today's load tests.